# unexpected end of file error in script file

Tags: bash, unix, shell

```
#!/bin/sh
#
Host = ###############
Port = ####
email_id="##################"
email_sub="######"
#
if ping -q -c 5 $Host >/dev/null
then
    result_host="Successful"
else
    result_host="Not Successful"
fi
result_nc='nc -z $Host $Port; echo $?'
if [ $result_nc != 0 ];
then
    result_port="Not Opened"
else
    result_port="Opened"
fi
mesg="Ping to host was ${result_host}, Port $port is ${result_port}."
echo "$mesg"
#echo "$mesg" | mail -s "$email_sub" $email_id
```

when i use to run the script am getting an error Syntax error: `Unexpected end of file.`

Comment: Is your script in DOS/Windows format (\r\n line endings) instead of unix (just \n)? You can use `cat -vet scriptname` to check (look for "^M$" at the ends of lines, instead of just "$").

Comment: On a related note: `if [ $result_nc != 0 ]` will not work. You should simply `if nc -z $Host $Port`
What you're doing is comparing the variable $result_nc ('nc -z $Host $Port; echo $?') with 0, which will never be true.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to run that. I did not get a syntax error. In fact it looks mostly good syntax wise.

Please see the output below:

```
$ ./a.sh
./a.sh: 3: ./a.sh: Host: not found
./a.sh: 4: ./a.sh: Port: not found
Usage: ping [-aAbBdDfhLnOqrRUvV] [-c count] [-i interval] [-I interface]
            [-m mark] [-M pmtudisc_option] [-l preload] [-p pattern] [-Q tos]
            [-s packetsize] [-S sndbuf] [-t ttl] [-T timestamp_option]
            [-w deadline] [-W timeout] [hop1 ...] destination
./a.sh: 15: [: nc: unexpected operator
Ping to host was Not Successful, Port  is Opened.
```

I think you want to replace the quotes in this line with backticks:

```
result_nc='nc -z $Host $Port; echo $?'
```

so change it to:

```
result_nc=`nc -z $Host $Port; echo $?`
```

There is also a logic problem (not a syntax issue) with that line because that assigns the stdout result of the command into result_nc. As Gordon suggested, change that to:

```
if nc -z $Host $Port
then
...
```

And remove the spaces in the assignment:

```
Host = ###############
Port = ####
```

so that becomes:

```
Host=###############
Port=####
```

because assignments will not work properly if there are spaces.

And do check out http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Also, the result_nc thing can be skipped entirely by using `if ! nc -z $Host $Port; then` (or `nc -z $Host $Port; result_nc=$?` if you actually need to store the exit code for some reason). I'll also recommend [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net) for basic sanity-checking.